# Do I need to complete the Via Infinito to gain 100% story completion?

Tags: final-fantasy-10-2

I'm working my way through X-2, and have just come up to the final dungeon.  I've followed the guide as closely as I can, but I seem to be missing some story completion percentage points.  I haven't completed the Via Infinito dungeon, since it seems to be harder than the end boss.  In the guide's story checklist, though, it includes that.

Googling this brings up conflicting answers.  Both for and against completing it.  I would like to know if I have to actually complete this to gain 100% in a single playthrough.  I would rather not have to play through it again, just to see the "Good" complete ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get 100% completion in a single playthrough, then *yes*, you do need to complete the Via Infinito.  All 100 floors.  If you plan on replaying the game to get 100%, then no, you don't need it.

It may actually be much faster to run through a very abbreviated game than to complete the Via Infinito again; it's incredibly hard, and the bosses pull no punches at all.  Several replays of bosses may be required.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can recall and what I looked up in some walkthroughs, you don't have to necessarily complete Via Infinito for the 100%. So *completing it* is essentially a sidequest.

However, you need to get the Crimson Sphere 6 and Crimson Sphere 8 from Cloisters 0 and 20, respectively, from Via Infinito.